# How to calculate two variables to sum the total from XML element Data then write to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

So I have the below code with help from @Tanaike but now I would like to know how to calculate the variables 'qty' minus 'availqty' then write the result to a column by replacing this code: `qty ? qty.getText() : "",`

Thanks in advance

```
  var totlistings = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('PaginationResult', NS).getChild('TotalNumberOfEntries', NS).getValue();
  //Logger.log(totlistings);
  
  var itms = root.getChild('ActiveList', NS).getChild('ItemArray', NS).getChildren();
  var values = itms.map(e => {
  var item = e.getChild('ItemID', NS);
  var title = e.getChild('Title', NS);
  var url = e.getChild('ListingDetails', NS).getChild('ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch', NS);
  var imgurl = e.getChild('PictureDetails', NS).getChild('GalleryURL', NS);
  var qty = e.getChild('Quantity', NS);
  var availqty = e.getChild('QuantityAvailable', NS)
  var sku = e.getChild('SKU', NS);
  
  
  //Logger.log(sum);
  return [sku ? sku.getText(): "", 
          availqty ? availqty.getText() : "",  
          qty ? qty.getText() : "", 
          item ? item.getText() : "", 
          title ? title.getText() : "", 
          url ? url.getText() : "", 
          imgurl ? imgurl.getText() : ""];
                            });  
   
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying some more I have manged to do it but for 3 days previous I struggled. Strange how I could see it once I had sent my question on here!

I swopped `qty ? qty.getText() : "",` with `qty ? qty.getText() - availqty.getText() : "",`